# OOXML: What does "Abstract Numbering Definition Type" mean?

Tags: openxml

[From the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.multileveltype(v=office.14).aspx) the description of this is *"This element specifies the type of numbering defined by a given abstract numbering type. This information shall only be used by a consumer to determine user interface behaviors for this numbering definition, and shall not be used to limit the behavior of the list (i.e. a list with multiple levels marked as singleLevel shall not be prevented from using levels 2 through 9). If this element is omitted, then the list shall be assumed to be of any numbering type desired by the consumer."*

`<w:multiLevelType w:val="multilevel"/>`

`<w:multiLevelType w:val="singlelevel"/>`

`<w:multiLevelType w:val="hybridmultilevel"/>`

What does this actually mean, and what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`singleLevel` means a list that has only a single level, like a simple bullet list or simple numbered list.

`multiLevel` means a list that can have multiple levels, but all levels start with bullets or start with text (number/letter).

`hybridMultiLevel` means a list that can have multiple levels and some levels can have bullets and other levels have text.

As the definition indicates, this is a user interface cue for the application. If you look at the three list toolbar buttons in Word, there each have a drop-down "library" of styles. This setting can be used by the application to determine which of these buttons the style should appear under.